# How to add 2 models in a registration form in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to create a Registration form which includes two models. One model is my custom model (Profile) and the other is the default User model in Django. I created two separate forms within the same template but the data is not successfully stored. This is what I had done so far:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
```

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():  
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'register_page.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['company', 'address']
```

However, when I tried to register a new user, the data gets saved in the User model (username, email, password) but not in the Profile model (company, address).

**I am getting this error instead:**

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /
Profile has no user.
```

What should I do?

Comment: You are not giving "user" (OneToOneField). This is not null field.

Comment: Meaning? I did not understand

Comment: Profile model is connected with User but you are not giving "user" field which connects Profile with User. Also, "user"  filed in Profile is not null field, you have to to provide value to this. check the answer, you will get the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `Profile` model is connected to the `User` model through `OneToOne` relation so you need to assign the user to your profile like this.:

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit = False)

             # assign user to your profile

            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Can you explain why did you assign 'user' to the profile.user variable?

Comment: because your profile model is connected to the user model through OneToOne relation

Comment: I just want to ask something.... hope you don't mind. What does the 'user' variable contain? When I printed out the user variable in my script, I am getting only the username. How does it know the user id then?

Comment: `user_form.save()` this is returning the instance of your `User` Model  so the `user` variable is the instance of the `User` model not the username.I don't know how did you get `username` maybe you printed `user.username`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you Arjun.

Comment: Altough this is 4 months old I would like to point that when you printed the intance of the `User` Model it calls the `__str__` method inside the model, which is very usual to be set like `return self.username`, that's why you get the username printed.